# Which version of mysql connector for .NET will access MySql 6.0?

Tags: asp.net

I want to connect to a MySql 6.0 database in my .net application.  What version of MySql connector for .NET should I use?

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

[Connector/Net 6.1](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html) should work.